# blockUI() not blocking

Tags: jquery, ajax, blockui

```
function load()  
{  
    var una=$('#un').val();  
    $.ajax({
        url:'student/checkuser.php?na='+una,
        type:'GET',
        success:function(data){
            if(data==1){alert('it works fine');}
            else{alert('re enter');}
        }
    });
}
$(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bt1').click(function(){
        $.blockUI();
        load();
    });
});
```

blockUI is not working
function is not working i have used the js files also both jquery and jquery.blockUI.js

Comment: If you want to block the UI for the duration of the Ajax call, why not just set `async: false` in `$.ajax()`?

Comment: thanxx for the reply but its still not working . the load () function started working but the ui is still not blocking